# Python3 проблема пустого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

```
User_File = open(File_Name, "r")
print(User_File.read())

User_File_List = User_File.read().split('\n')
print(User_File_List)
```

До этого кода в файл записывается текст, после этой части кода программа выдает:

```
Hello.\nMy name is Roman.\nI am 25.\nI am an Engineer.
```

То есть он сначала читает его, а потом делит, но файл пустой?

Comment: print(User_File.read()) читает весь файл, для User_File.read().split('\n') ничего не остается... закоментируйте первый принт?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Файл - это поток последовательного чтения (и/или записи). Если вы открыли и прочитали весь файл, то он кончился и больше его нельзя прочитать ещё раз. Для того, чтобы прочитать файл ещё раз, нужно либо его закрыть и открыть заново, либо перейти на начало файла с помощью `User_File.seek(0)`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @РоманКрамарев, не забудьте [проголосовать за понравившиеся ответы и принять тот, что помог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 4):

В третьей строке в User_File_List ничего нет, т.к. на предыдущей файл вычитан целиком, выведен на печать и не закрыт.

Лучше так: код вычитывает файл, печатает и закрывает файл:

```
with open(File_Name, 'r') as file:
    # read & print the entire file
    print(file.read())
```

Так вычитывает файл, сплитует, печатает и закрывает файл:

```
with open(File_Name, 'r') as file:
    # read & print the entire file with split
    print(file.read().split('\n'))
```

PS про [менеджер контекста](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)

Comment: От души благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Про причины такого поведения вам написали в других ответах.

В данном случае можно записать прочитанные данные в переменную, вывести эти данные, потом эти же данные разбивать на отдельные строки, не читая их заново из файла:

```
text = User_File.read()
print(text)

User_File_List = text.split('\n')
print(User_File_List)
```

Comment: Не используйте `open().read()`, а используйте менеджмент контекста. В таком случае только в новом `cpython` это собирается в мусор. В других реализациях вроде нет. Сильно не рекомендую так делать, особенно если у вас старая версия.

Comment: @FotonPC, в общем, я убрал open, чтобы никого не смущало. Про то что есть какие-то проблемы со сборкой мусора - впервые слышу. Единственно, при открытии без менеджера контекста нужно файл самостоятельно закрывать, но это не проблемы со сборкой мусора, это просто незакрытый файл.